# How can I associate who can open a "new work item" to user group?

Tags: tfs

I have in my server 2 groups of people "Admins" and "users"
In TFS  , i  want that only "Admins" would be **able** to open `a new work item` and users **won't** be able to.

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project in team explorer

Choose Area and iteration

Choose the Area you want and click security

You can assign the permission

Edit work item in this node

View work item in this node

Thanks

M.Radwan

Answer (score 0):

You should put all Admins in a TFS user group and modify all work item definitions separately, to allow only users from this group to create a work item using the "For" field of the default transition.